# Insert SQL query result into table column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this PostgreSQL table for storing words:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('processed_words_id_seq'::regclass),
    keyword character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    trademark_blacklisted character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
);

insert into words (keyword,trademark_blacklisted)
VALUES ('while swam is interesting', 'ibm is a company');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trademarks
(
   id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('trademarks_id_seq'::regclass),
   trademark character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
)

insert into words (keyword,trademark_blacklisted)
VALUES ('swam', 'ibm');
```

Into table `trademarks` I will have thousands of registered trademarks names.
I want to compare words stored into `words` table keyword do they match not only for a words but also for word which is a in a group of words. For example:

I have a keyword `while swam is interesting` stored into `words.keyword`. I also have a trademark `swam` located in `trademarks.trademark` I have a word match so I want to detect this using SQL.

Possible solution:

```
select w.id, w.keyword, t.trademark 
from words w
inner join trademarks t on w.keyword::tsvector @@ 
regexp_replace(t.trademark, '\s', ' | ', 'g' )::tsquery;
```

I get error:

```
ERROR:  no operand in tsquery: "Google | "
SQL state: 42601
```

How I can implement this properly and insert the result into table column `words.trademark_blacklisted`? Is it possible to limit it to search by param? For example search for only one word is it blacklisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    w.id, w.keyword, t.trademark 
from
    words w
inner join 
    trademarks t 
on
  t.trademark ilike  '%'||w.keyword||'%' 
where 
   w.keyword = <some_value>;
```

Using the case insensitive version of [LIKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE).

Comment: I tested the query - it's taking too much time for execution. Is it possible to limit it to search by param? For example search for only one word is it blacklisted?

Comment: `... where w.keyword = <some_value>`

Comment: Can you update the SQL query please?

Comment: And lastly as described into the post how I can insert the result if blacklisted word is found into table row?

Comment: Insert what? There could be many trademarks that contain the word. How do you want to handle that? Update your question with an example. Also it would be an update not an insert if I am following correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple; cross-join the two tables and say

```
Where POSITION(trademark in keyword)>0
```

Comment: ...not particularly fast, but I`m not sure you can make it fast without some preprocessing,.

Comment: Can you paste the complete query please? Including the insert.

Answer (score 0):

I am new in this area, but you can try the below query.

```
INSERT INTO words (trademark_blacklisted)
SELECT t.trademark
FROM words w
INNER JOIN trademarks t ON t.trademark ILIKE '%'||w.keyword||'%'
WHERE w.keyword = 'swam'
```